# Moving large files using shutil.move

Tags: python

I have written a code for moving files from one folder to another .I moved only those files whose names are present in my text file(aiq.txt).
It works fine when files are less in number say(10) but when number goes to around 500 the program terminates.
Each file is of 50 Mb
    Here is my code:

```
import os
import shutil
destination=r"dstpath"
with open("aiq.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line=line.strip('\n)
        for root,dirs,filenames in os.walk(r"H:\test_vectors"):
            for filename in filenames:
                if line in filename:
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(root,filename),destination)
```

Comment: "the program terminates." Does it throw an error?

Comment: What does that mean? Do you execute this Python program in a shell? Does this shell terminate? What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows .As soon as I run the script ,it runs for 4 secs and then stops

Comment: How are you running the program?  Are you launching it from Windows Explorer or from cmd.exe?

Comment: That is a really scary script. I hope you backed up your disk before running it.  What it will actually do is to look through the lines of aiq.txt and move any file whose name matches one of the lines, or has a longer name that *contains* one of the lines - because of "if line in filename."  So if one of your lines is "a", all files with a name containing an "a" will be moved.  All the files will be moved to a destination file "dstpath" which will be overwritten each time, and each source file will then be deleted.  Is this really what you want?

Comment: @paul: each line in aiq.txt is a exact filename

Comment: @paul: real problem is the number of files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import shutil

root = r"H:\test_vectors"
destination = r"dstpath"

file_list = []
dir_dict = {}

with open('aiq.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        file_list.append(line.strip())

for d, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
    if files:
        dir_dict[d] = files

for key, item in dir_dict.items():
    for x in item:
        if x in file_list:
              try:
                  shutil.move(os.path.join(key, x), destination)
              except:
                  pass
```

Comment: Sorry I missed this point. Probably you need to create some kind of dictionary, where key is full path to a subdirectory and the value is a filename. Then find intersection between list from file and values from dictionary

Comment: :could you plz write the code as I am fairly new to python

Comment: Do you have in those subdirectories files with the same name?

Comment: i mean two files with the same name in two different dirs. If you already move such file from first dir, how do you suppose to move file with the same name to the destionation? You need to overwrite already existed or discard

Comment: there is no problem in overwriting

Comment: I wanted to know if this script will work for 500 files which are around 50 Mb each

Comment: I think this code is more complex because it goes through each file in the source folder . In my code i have taken each line from my txt file and go through the source folder only once

Comment: "I think this code is more complex because it goes through each file in the source folder . In my code i have taken each line from my txt file and go through the source folder only once" - not true.  In your code the loop through the folders is inside the loop through the txt file; therefore you will step through the folders once FOR EACH LINE in the txt file (500 times!).  Andrey's code steps through the directories only once, since he had no nested loop.

Comment: You still haven't explained why you think the program is terminating.  Why don't you replace the shutil.move with a print statement, so each time you want to move a file you see its name printed instead?  Then you can see when or why the program is stopping.

Comment: I think the problem is that you change you subdirectories structure (move files) while iterating over them. I divided the code into two parts - get the info about all files and execute file operations then.